A use case for the 'r' suffix to the substitution command in GNU Ed?
I am running GNU Ed on Fedora Linux. The GNU Ed manual cryptically refers to an 'r' suffix for the s command, to be distinguished from the 'r' command. All it says about it is the following:

The suffix 'r' causes the re of the last search to be used instead of the re of the last substitution (if the search happened after the substitution).

I cannot see its usefulness especially if one uses Ed with rlwrap, with which one can easily modify the last substitution. Can someone provide a use case for 'r' as a suffix?

How does it not "seem to work"? Please add input to ed and expected output.

That last paragraph is a bit ironic: a lot of people probably won't see the usefulness of ed, especially if they can use pretty much anything else. I don't use it, but I can imagine how someone might find it convenient to do s/nofoo/foo/, then /nobar and finally s//bar/r, and have it use nobar as the pattern instead of nofoo. I think this is the default behaviour in Vim, without needing any suffixes

If I try out your example in Ed, I get ?

@muru That should be sr as a shorthand for re-applying the substitution with the most recent regular expression (either from a search or a substitution) with the most recent replacement.  It's a GNU thing, but could probably be quite useful to someone who uses this editor a lot.

@Kusalananda ah thanks for the correction.

@Kusalananda, yes, it doesn't seem to be a feature of the Unix version of Ed.

The linked manual states that the syntax of the s command is:

(.,.)s/re/replacement/[suffixes]


and

ed can repeat the last substitution using the following alternative syntax for the 's' command:
(.,.)s[suffixes]

[...] The suffix 'r' causes the re of the last search to be used instead of the re of the last substitution (if the search happened after the substitution).

Here, re stands for regular expression. To use the r suffix to the s command, first the s command needs to be executed, then the search (eg. with //), then the s command with only the suffix (as there would be no point in specifying the s command in the form s/re/replacement/, since it specifies a re):
$ cat <<! >example.text
> Hello, world!
> The quick brown fox
> !
$ ed example.text
34
1
Hello, world!
s/\(\([[:alpha:]]\{1,\}\)o\)/"\1"/
1p
"Hello", world!
/\(\(quick brown\)\)/
The quick brown fox
sr
,p
"Hello", world!
The "quick brown" fox

